# Modelling planar molecules and their evolutions

Tags: polymers, structural-biology, geochemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

I am trying to simulate a chain of molecules which are planar.

Can anyone please give me an example of the molecular chain which can stay as planar with it's minimum energy state is planar. A published study on the evolution of the geometry of the molecule will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-dimensional Fabre and Bechgaard salts, TTF-TCNQ,

[image]

http://www.chem.tamu.edu/rgroup/dunbar/Publications/2002-147.pdf 
platinum blues

DOI:10.1002/asia.200700370 
hexaphenylbenzene discotic liquid crystals 
http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781439811436 
"Chemistry of Discotic Liquid Crystals: From Monomers to Polymers," Sandeep Kumar (2010)

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-2319-0_16 
middle 
http://physics.aps.org/synopsis-for/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.180401 
  Organic magnets

http://pubs.acs.org/cen/topstory/8201/8201notw8.html 
Ladderanes

[image: Ladderanes]

stacks 
http://www.google.com/patents/WO2011017711A2?cl=en 
http://www.halcyon.com/nanojbl/Images/ConPoly3.gif 
and a central hexacoordinate silicon with oxygen bridges

Comment: I think you missed graphite.

Comment: "simulate chain of molecules" Graphite is 2-D planar not 1-D chain.  I think you missed h-BN, MgB2, zirconium phosphonates, smectite clays, micas, FeO(OH), FeCl2, heavy metal dichalcogenides...Langmuir-Blodgett depositions...DOI:10.1039/C001929A, http://chemistry.aalto.fi/en/research/groups/inorganic_chemistry/ etc.