# Modelling planar ring molecules and their evolutions

Tags: polymers, structural-biology, cis-trans-isomerism

This is the next step of my previous [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10257/modelling-planar-molecules-and-their-evolutions).

I am trying to simulate a circular chain (ring) of molecules which are planar (two dimensional). What I do is take a planar unknot and embed it into a two dimensional lattice. Then I calculate energy of the unknot and try to evolve the unknot so that it reaches the canonical form. By definition it then has the minimum energy. To have a realistic definition of the energy I need to study real life planar unknots.

Can anyone please give me an example of the molecular chain which can stay as planar with it's minimum energy state is planar. A published study on the evolution of the geometry of the molecule will be highly helpful.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more what you actually mean and what you try to accomplish. I also do not understand what 'evolution of geometry' should be?

Comment: @Martin, I have added some background.

Comment: Do you mean something like the heme ligand? And what do you mean by evolution of the geometry?

Comment: @Martin, by 'evolution of geometry' I meant changes in shape.

Comment: What are you looking at? Molecules in gas, liquid or solid phase? Are we dealing with solutions? Molecules change their shape depending on the environment constantly (rotations, vibrations). One has to consider chemical equilibria. Only to name a few. I do not think you can call that evolution. If you are referring to simulations, where in a given timeframe the orientation of the entities change, that is something else. It is really hard to understand what you are asking for. I guess I am not the only one and I would be glad to help.

Comment: @Martin, for the time being I would like to investigate  molecules in a solution. I am trying to keep it as simple as possible. I think polymer rings in a solution is the simplest scenario, right?